# how to replace a value with a string in an array with python

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of data and I would like to replace all the values that are greater than 50 with a string saying 'INDE'. How could I do this in python?

I tried this:

```
import numpy as np

row={'time': 10, 'tsys_1': [85.1, 91.8, 94.3, 37.1, 12.2, 17.4, 78.5, 68.8],'subarray': 1}

data=np.array(row['tsys_1'][0:8])

for i in range(len(data)):
    if data[i] > 50:
        data[i] = 'INDE'
```

But then this error occur:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: INDE
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Don't use `np.array` just `data = row['tsys_1'][0:8]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably better to just do this in pure python.

```
>>> row['tsys_1'] = ['INDE' if x > 50 else x for x in row['tsys_1']]
>>> row
{'subarray': 1,
 'time': 10,
 'tsys_1': ['INDE', 'INDE', 'INDE', 37.1, 12.2, 17.4, 'INDE', 'INDE']}
```

Having a numpy array which is a mixture of string and numbers kinda defeats the purpose of having a numpy array in the first place.  However, if you really want that, here's how you could get it:

```
>>> data = np.array(row['tsys_1'][0:8]).astype(object)
>>> data[data > 50] = 'INDE'
>>> data
array(['INDE', 'INDE', 'INDE', 37.1, 12.2, 17.4, 'INDE', 'INDE'], dtype=object)
```

If you want to mask out these values in numpy, you might want to look at using a masked array (in `numpy.ma`) or use something like `np.nan` for your masked value instead of this string `'INDE'`.

Comment: thank you, I used numpy.ma to mask this values and I get what I wanted.